Epub: trying to resolve issues
I am having problems uploading an epub file to Ingramsparks  (fixed not flowing as I am uploading a picture book) as attached.    I am advised that this is a coding issue. Accordingly can anyone confirm and if so would learning HTML/XHTML assist? Any direction would be very helpful.
Many thanks
I have tried googles epub version, i have tried various conversion software unfortunately there is always a problem. I was expecting doc to be uploaded without a prob

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have attached the doc showing prob

Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question and revise your post to provide some code.
